# Cypher: grouping/relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm new to Cypher/graph DBs. I created a example to understand traversals but not quite getting it.

```
//Cypher below to create nodes.
(`0` :Person {id:'74474',Name:"Mr. Dan"}) ,
  (`1` :Company {id:'1234',Name:"Company A"}) ,
  (`2` :Company {id:'1111',Name:"Company B"}) ,
  (`3` :Person {id:'0844',Name:"Mr.X"}) ,
  (`4` :Person {id:'3455',Name:"Mr. Jack"}) ,
  (`5` :Person {id:'748222',Name:"Mr.Y"}) ,
  (`0`)-[:`owns` {amt:'50%'}]->(`1`),
  (`4`)-[:`owns` {amt:'30%'}]->(`1`),
  (`2`)-[:`owns` {amt:'20%'}]->(`1`),
  (`3`)-[:`owns` {amt:'30%'}]->(`2`),
  (`5`)-[:`owns` {amt:'70%'}]->(`2`)
// end
```

Query : 
MATCH (p:Person)-[o:owns*]->(c:Company)
where c.Name="Company A"
return p, o
//

this gives me all "Persons" who own "Company A" but I want to get the "% ownership" of each Person.

I cant seem to extract or aggregate the values in the relationship "o". Seemed easy but I seem challenged!

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please format your code so it's readable for us!

Comment: MATCH (p:Person)-[o:owns*]->(c:Company) where c.Name="Company A" return p, o.amt, c

Comment: @logisima- not working, not sure the intent of adding c. I am trying to aggregate the "amts" for each person. So for Person, if there are two "amts" in the relationship path, then it should aggregate (multiply in this case). but even if I can aggregate them thats a start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one, it will be easier to multiply your ownership amounts if you use numeric values rather than a string value. They'll need to be in decimal format, `.5` instead of `'50%'`.

Maybe try something like this (after changing your amt values to floats), using REDUCE() to multiply all amounts across the relationships in the path:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[owns:owns*]->(c:Company) 
WHERE c.Name="Company A"
RETURN p, reduce(amt = 1, o in owns | amt * o.amt) as percentOwned
```

A thing to keep in mind is that a variable on a variable-length relationship (where we use *) will reference a collection of relationships, not a single relationship.

Comment: thanks @InverseFalson, strangely enough. I reached the same solution through trial and error. Realized the % are not handled well and also reduce is the only function that works.